# PubNub SDK with custom Framework

Tags: ios, frameworks, pubnub

We are building a Framework in iOS which uses PubNub SDK. We have successfully build the framework. I have also added the depending frameworks to the application project and also the framework project. When integrating the framework in an application project, the application crashes giving the following log:

-[__NSDate consoleOutputTimestamp]: unrecognised selector sent to instance 0x8e9e930

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSDate consoleOutputTimestamp]: unrecognised selector sent to instance 0x8e9e930'

This happens when calling the method  [PubNub setDelegate:self]; in one of the classes of framework project.

Comment: Hi! This is not normal! Please contact us at support@pubnub.com, and we'll help you narrow down the issue... please attach the sample app when you contact us, it will help us got you up and running in no time.

Comment: I have contacted the support team and also I have provided a Demo app. Waiting for the solution.